# How to recursively loop through multidimensional array to get a key match

Tags: php, arrays

I have this variable and array. I want to loop through the array keys and if there is a match with `$cat` value I want to get the array key name which its belong to `Architecture & Design`. How can I do this? Thank you

```
$cat = 'sound';

Array
(
    [Architecture & Design] => Array
        (
            [0] => architecture
            [1] => fashion
            [2] => game
            [3] => graphic
            [4] => interior
            [5] => industrial
            [6] => textile
            [7] => web
            [8] => ui
            [9] => sound
        )

    [Test array] => Array
        (
            [0] => item1
            [1] => item2
            [2] => item3
            [3] => item4
            [4] => item5
            [5] => item6
            [6] => item7
            [7] => item8
            [8] => item9
            [9] => item0
        )

)
```

Comment: Didn't I get your question correct? What's the point in printing `Architecture & Design` as the answer?

Comment: No your answer was okay. Thanks for that. I just found Aksen's solution more suitable for my situation.

Comment: Ok, the wording of your question seems different for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use next function with foreach loop:

```
$cat = 'sound';

function get_key($array,$cat){

    foreach($array as $key=>$subar){

        foreach($subar as $val){
            if ($val === $cat) return $key;  
        }  

    }
    return '';
}

echo get_key($data,$cat);
```

It will produce to you the first appearance.

**[Demo](https://3v4l.org/RHIuf)**

Comment: You may need to check this,

Comment: @RiggsFolly, some problems with special chars could be?)

Comment: No, look again at the shape of the OP's array

Comment: @RiggsFolly, Oh, I see. Thank you, wrote it without demo checking

Comment: @AksenP Thanks for your solution. I'm a bit new to php. May I ask why you have included `return '';` at the end of the loop?

Comment: @SujanRavishka, it's a default value of the method. It means, that if foreach loop won't find a value, then this method [won't return anything](https://3v4l.org/NNFBq) - `NULL`. In case of `''` - it has a string datatype always.

Answer (score 2):

Loop over your array with key value pair. If the key is `Architecture & Design`, skip it, else continue with other keys. If you find a value in them equal to `$cat`, print what the respective value is in `Architecture & Design`.

```
<?php 

$cat = 'item1';


foreach($array as $key => $value){
    if($key === 'Architecture & Design') continue;
    foreach($value as $index => $val){
        if($cat === $val){
            echo $val, " " , $array['Architecture & Design'][$index],PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `foreach` loop with `key` and `value`:

https://paiza.io/projects/J3hi4BM51b3-2jq2ayperw

```
foreach($arr["Architecture & Design"] as $key => $value){
    if($value === $cat){
        echo $key;
    }
}
```